# Python, keras, Convolutional autoencoder

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

I'm trying create my first convolutional autoencoder in keras but I have problems with layer output shape. There is my code:

```
input_img = Input(shape=X_train.shape[1:])

x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3))(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3))(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3))(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3))(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
print(autoencoder.summary())
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')
autoencoder.fit(X_train, X_train, epochs=50, batch_size=32)
```

and result:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param   
=================================================================
input_87 (InputLayer)        (None, 32, 32, 3)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_327 (Conv2D)          (None, 32, 32, 3)         9248      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_136 (MaxPoolin (None, 32, 16, 2)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_328 (Conv2D)          (None, 16, 16, 2)         4624      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_137 (MaxPoolin (None, 16, 8, 1)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_329 (Conv2D)          (None, 16, 8, 1)          2320      
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_124 (UpSamplin (None, 16, 16, 2)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_330 (Conv2D)          (None, 32, 16, 2)         4640      
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_125 (UpSamplin (None, 32, 32, 4)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_331 (Conv2D)          (None, 1, 32, 4)          289       
=================================================================
Total params: 21,121
Trainable params: 21,121
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

And of course error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv2d_331 to have shape (None, 1, 32, 4) but got array with shape (50000, 32, 32, 3)
```

Have you any idea what I'm doing wrong? Why last UpSampling2D return that shape?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47822154/layer-conv2d-3-was-called-with-an-input-that-isnt-a-symbolic-tensor any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it seems that your `keras` has set its image dimension to `channel_first` (and probably `Theano` as a backend) what means that the last two dimensions of your input are treated as spatial dimension instead of 2nd and 3rd. Another thing is that your output should have `3` filters instead of `1` beacuse this will end up in target dimension mismatch. To sum up:

1. In order to set your input correctly you need to either switch to `tensorflow` and change channel ordering to `channel_last` or transpose your input by:

   ```
   X = X.transpose([0, 3, 1, 2])
   ```
2. Change the following line:

   ```
   decoded = Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)
   ```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47842931/valueerror-error-when-checking-target-expected-model-2-to-have-shape-none-25 any suggestions?